# how to use secret key in flask

Tags: flask, secret-key

I am using Flask application.

I got this error
The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
how to solve??

I am using Flask application.
I started my code like this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'memory'
Session(app)
```

I got this error
The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
how to solve??

Answer (score 0):

According to Flask-Session [documentation](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#configuration), you have the following configuration options for SESSION_TYPE:

null, redis, memcached, filesystem, mongodb, sqlalchemy

Change your SESSION_TYPE="memory" to SESSION_TYPE="filesystem", and you will no longer have the error.